# Initializing a class with an array?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

With STL's vector class I can initialize a vector using a list (or array) of items:

```
std::vector<int> = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Is it possible for me to implement this functionality into my own classes? I am writing my own Vector class for practice implementing data structures and would like to do:

```
MyVectorClass<int> = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Look at `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Define a constructor in your class that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>`:

```
MyVectorClass(std::initializer_list<T> initializer)
{
    for(T& i : initializer)
    {
        // Do whatever you want with items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course. It's one of the design goals of C++ that the standard library can be implemented in the language (with a few notable exceptions).

What you are looking for is called `std::initializer_list`. It is *not* an array! See [`std::vector` constructor documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: It might be worth giving an example of these exceptions, or linking to a list.